# How to create a pattern out of grid in perspective

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, grids

I’m trying to create a seamless pattern out of the grid below but cannot figure out how to do so. Whatever I do the lines don’t line up perfectly. I’m trying to keep the sample as big as possible because after I get this right, some small icons are going to be placed on top of each line intersection.

[image]

How do I go about doing this?

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **never** need to create an angled line pattern in Illustrator. Seriously **never**.

Simply create a *straight* line pattern, then *rotate* the pattern tiles..

- Create the artwork of a *straight* grid
- Drag the art to the **Swatches Panel** to create the pattern swatch
- Draw new object and fill with pattern
- Double-click the **Rotate Tool** (or choose `Object > Transform > Rotate` from the menu)
- **UNTICK** the `Transform Objects` box...
- rotate your pattern *without* rotating the object...
- You can then use the **Free Transform Tool** to reduce the height of the object and the pattern will take on a perspective appearance.

[image]

---

Before others ask.... Photoshop ***can not*** do this.

---

Comment: Thanks! I never payed attention to rotate tool. But how would you go about adding icons to the cross sections without distorting them in perspective and creating a grid out of them?

Comment: If you are seeking to create an isometric image, then a pattern fill probably isn't want you want and isn't going to work. Or place your icon images separately above the pattern-filled shape. Don't make icons part of the pattern.